# How to set http header for for HTTP in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, http, get

I am trying to implement Http in IOS.

I use the following code to send `GET` command to the Server.

```
SERVER_IP        = @"xxx.xx.xxx.xxx";
PORT             = @"12345";
USER_ID             = @"1234-1234-1234-1234-1234";
USER_PWD             = @"123456";
url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@:%@/message/user/%@",SERVER_IP,PORT,USER_ID]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSDictionary *header = [request allHTTPHeaderFields];
    [header setValue:@"Authorization" forKey:USER_PWD];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@",html);
    }];
```

It show `**The resource requires authentication, which was not supplied with the request**` at the log.

I have set the parameter `header` , but I don't know how to use it.

Can someone help me and teach me how to implement `GET` command and setting password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
[request setValue:@"xxx" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

But you have to change the `NSURLRequest` to `NSMutableURLRequest`, please check [Zaph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26035936/1091539)'s answer

Answer (score 1):

The header information is added to the URLRequest.

Create a `NSMutableURLRequest` and use the `setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:` method to add the header to the request.

There are many other setting available for `NSMutableURLRequest`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the header on the NSURLRequest somehow, something like that will do.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setValue:USER_PWD forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an NSDictionary with all your header fields and use the following command to set the required headers.

```
NSDictionary *dictHeader = @{@"Content-Type": @"application/octet-stream", 
@"Authorization": @"accessToken"};

[request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:dictHeader];
```